# how to play my recording with everyplay (for iOS)

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-x, playback, recording, everyplay

I'm trying to use everyplay to record my game,but I don't know which method can play my recording.

I tried:

```
[[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] stopRecording];
[[Everyplay sharedInstance] playLastRecording];
```

there is no error occurring, but no play either, only a connecting sign.

I'm running the game in simulator

Comment: then run it on a device to confirm that this is a real issue! If something's not right on the simulator ignore it, the simulator ain't perfect and specifically sound support can be sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

To test the recording part of Everyplay, you need to run the application on an actual device, the recording is not enabled in simulator versions and therefore the playLastRecording fails.

Comment: thx, got it! But now I have another question about everyplay:see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737450/everyplay-causes-my-screen-size-change. Any help thanks