# everyplay causes my screen size change

Tags: cocos2d-x, screen-size, everyplay

used cocos2d-x(version:"cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.1") under xcode

I set

```
CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->setDesignResolutionSize(960, 640, kResolutionShowAll)
```

to make my game fit different devices. With Everyplay effect on, my screen size will change auto, only happened when test on real machine, but no such bug when I use kResolutionExactFit.
However, I need to use kResolutionShowAll. 
With iphone4 it works all well,but with ipad and iphone 5(I think all devices except screen size is 960*640) have the bug above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Everyplay v1.6.3.